# Restricting user editing in parse based on a column type

Tags: security, parse-platform

I have a Parse Users table and I have an admin interface for users who are of type admin. Every user has a column that they are grouped by, lets call this Area column.

The admin interface only shows others users that have the same Area. How can I assure at a security level that they can only ever edit users with the same area?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two main ways to do this. If you want to be able to edit other users from the client side of things, you'll need to use ACLs.  You will have to create roles for each area, and add admins of each area to those roles.  You will need to set up users so that their ACL includes write access for their area's role.  This will probably need to be put into a beforeSave call. Check to see if the area is dirty, and if so, remove write permissions for their previous area's role and set up write permissions for their new area's role.

The second way of doing this is to use cloud functions that specify `{useMasterKey:true}` in the required methods.  This additional parameter overrides any CLPs or ACLs for that method.  Then you can set up manual checks to see if the user who called the function is an admin and if they are an admin of the appropriate area. If so, allow them to make the changes.

You can find documentation on how to set up CLPs and ACLs in the guide for whichever API you are using.

Edit - As @Alvaro's edit points out, `Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey()` has been deprecated. You used to be able to call that at the top of cloud functions, and it would implicitly pass the master key into individual Parse methods. Now, you have to pass it explicitly. I.e. `object.fetch({useMasterKey:true});` or `query.find({useMasterKey:true});`

Comment: Which is the easiest most maintainable way? Thanks

Comment: Also once the user has been created they will have the same area as the admin and this can't be changed. Is this possible?

Comment: Setting the ACL sounds like the most appropriate way. You can also have a super admin role, and set them to have write access for all users in the CLP (Class Level Permissions).

Comment: You will still have to set the area somewhere initially.  You could have a beforeSave trigger for your users that checks to see if the area isDirty, and if it is, only call success() if a newlyRegistered bool is both dirty and true? That seems like a possible approach to me.

Comment: They thing is that I don't want a user to register, but only be created by admins. It is possible? Or must a somehow find a way to give a newly register user an area by some special way.

Comment: At some point you are going to have to create the user object. I believe that the only things you create at first are the email, password, and username fields. Then you need to update whatever other data you have for a new user. At that time, any field you update is going to be "dirty", or changed, from the default (undefined). The only way to not allow individual parameters to be changed is by calling response.error() on the beforeSave() trigger when that key is dirty. However, you need to be able to change it the first time, so a newlyRegistered bool that is dirty and true means user is new.

Comment: Sometimes I wonder if it would be just easier doing all this in mongo, where I wouldn't have all this vendor specific stuff..

Comment: I've never used Mongo, but I've found Parse to be very powerful and customizable, once you figure out how to do what you need to do.  It isn't overly complex, although there are a lot of nuances you pick up over time.